# How to set up own paclet server?

Tags: packages, internet, paclets

With the paclet management framework made public in v12.1, I am eager to automate package distribution and update via paclets over the net. Stephen Wolfram mentioned in [this post about v12.1](https://blog.wolfram.com/2020/03/18/in-less-than-a-year-so-much-new-launching-version-12-1-of-wolfram-language-mathematica/) that they inted to make their paclet repository open to anyone in the near future.

However, I want to host a private server (for company policy reasons) to serve paclets for users who have minimal experience with Mathematica. Therefore I cannot expect them to do anything more complicated than `PacletInstall["MyPaclet"]` any time I roll out a new version, assuming they have already registered the server (which is done only once as paclet sites are persistent). Paclet (`PacletObject`) and paclet site (`PacletSiteObject`) management is certainly more polished in v12.1 than before, but I fail to set up my own site (e.g. a GitHub repo) as a paclet server. I have a GitHub account and I've uploaded the generated `PacletSite.mz`, but whatever I try, I get this error, which is not very informative. Did I use a wrong URL? Is the `PacletSite.mz` file wrong? Or code could not find it?

```
PacletSiteUnregister["MyGitHub"];
PacletSiteRegister["http://raw.githubusercontent.com/IstvanZachar/[...]", "MyGitHub"];
PacletSiteUpdate["MyGitHub"]

PacletSiteUpdate::err: An error occurred attempting to update paclet information
from site http://raw.githubusercontent.com/IstvanZachar/[...]. Does not appear to
be a valid paclet site
```

I have many questions, but here are the essential ones. This post (and answers) may serve as a knowledgebase for paclet server setup for a wide range of use cases.

- How to host a paclet server in an arbitrary location
  (i.e. other than the Wolfram Cloud or local)?
- What are the requirements for a site to qualify? Must use `http://` instead of `https://`? Should transparently provide path for (sub)directories and files (like GitHub and unlike Google Drive)?
- What are the minimum requirements for the paclet server for `PacletSiteUpdate` to be able to successfully query an uploaded `PacletSite.mz`? What other files needed to be there? I assume that actual paclet files are not needed for testing `PacletSiteUpdate`, as it uses the descriptor `PacletSite.mz`, but I may be wrong.
- What protocol to use and how to refer to site architecture when registering the site via `PacletSiteRegister`?
- How is a paclet site checked for consistency by `PacletSiteUpdate` and upon what conditions `PacletSiteUpdate` find a site a `valid paclet site`?

I am aware of these posts, but they are from 2-4 years before (using now obsolete functions) plus I could not create a working paclet server based on them.

- [How to distribute Mathematica packages as paclets?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/131101/89)
- [How can I use GitHub as a paclet server?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155123/89)
- [Finding paclets on a server](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/163845/89)
- [Installing a Paclet from GitHub (or other non-paclet server site)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/152660/89)
- [How can I set up a local paclet server? (easy package sharing via shared DropBox)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/156041/89)
- [Hosting a curated data function / server in Google Drive](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/146832/89)
- [Create your own Paclet Site](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/968760?p_p_auth=VCLLf3ed)

Comment: Did you see the links at the top of this post? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1668/12

Answer (score 2):

Here is a package with utilities for manage a paclet site, especially a paclet site on Github:

https://github.com/rnotlnglgq/WolframPacletSiteManager

---

### Basic Usage

1. Put your paclets like this:

- Git repository

  - .git/
  - Paclets/

    - MyPaclet-0.0.1.paclet
    - MyPaclet-0.0.2.paclet

2. Execute `wolframscript -code 'PutSiteInfo[]'` **in the git repository**, then you will get:

- Git repository

  - .git/
  - Paclets/

    - YourPaclet-0.0.1.paclet
    - YourPaclet-0.0.2.paclet
  - PacletSite.m (This file is not necessary)
  - PacletSite.mz (will be read by the PacletManager)

3. Commit and push the git repository to remote
4. Guide users of your paclet installing your paclet with:

```
PacletInstall["YourPaclet", "Site"->"https://github.com/you/repo/raw/branch"]
```

The url `raw.githubusercontent.com` is also OK for github repositories.

---

This paclet is still in development, but I think there isn't anything fatal.

> Different from some other implemented packages, this package is not developed mainly for distributing paclets, but for keeping a paclet site synchronous with another one.

Comment: So basically, your package does the same as the functions in the ``PacletManager` `` context? Could you please elaborate on how your method differs e.g. from using the domestic ``PacletManager`BuildPacletSiteFiles``?

Comment: @IstvánZachar This package provides paclet splitting and site synchronization utilities, which are used for building a paclet mirror on a remote git repository. `PacletManager` functions may change, and I suffered some from that update `4.0.0->5.0.0` . So I define functions needed on my own instead of using those in ``` PacletManager` ```. And here're also some new useful function like: `PacletSearch["ExampleData"]`.

Comment: Can your package access a private repository on GitHub? Can `GetSiteInfo` pass on Headers to the HTTPRequest to download `PacletSite.mz` if a Personal Authentication Token is known?

Comment: @IstvánZachar No, it can't. In fact, this paclet is not developed for Github but for another online git repository site: Gitee.